# Is there a way of ejecting an external drive using python without shelling out

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10

Title basically says it all. I'm trying to write a script for backing up my files and I want the script to eject the drive it is backing the data up to after its done copying things. I couldn't really find anything online for libraries or builtin methods of doing this. OS is windows 10.

I apologize in advance if I'm doing something wrong, kind of unfamiliar with SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3174349/6770384

Comment: I appreciate having a solution for sure @Socowi but gosh, having the optimal solution being calling ctypes and running a C# function with a string with space separated values makes me think that we never should have evolved past raw machine code.