# Eject and Close CD/DVD Devices IN C#

Tags: c#, media, cddvd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programatically ejecting and retracting the CD drive in vb.net or c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449410/programatically-ejecting-and-retracting-the-cd-drive-in-vb-net-or-c)

I want to Eject and Close Multiple DVD or CD Devices on a pc using c#.
I also would like to detect which are IDE, SATA and SCSI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open or close CD

http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1692.htm

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449410/programatically-ejecting-and-retracting-the-cd-drive-in-vb-net-or-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

See [IOCTL_CDROM_LOAD_MEDIA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559352.aspx).